# Generate large length column using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I want to store user's reports. The database is autogenerated by Hibernate based on the Java entities.

What is the best way to specify, that the `String report` will contain a large portion of information?

The options are:

- `@Column(length = xxxx) - this looks like more portable`
- `@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT") - doesn't work on some databases`
- `@Lob - not sure what are pros/cons`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of using `@Column(length = xxxx)` is their portability. If you know you're not changing the database, you can use the second option and check for a native Type.
Otherwise use the first option. The `@Lob` could lead to problems if you need to search the text inside the field, because it can be considered as binary.